# Mysql query very slow and not using proper index (By using group by, IN operator )

Tags: mysql, performance, query-tuning

Below query was taking 5+ sec time to execute ( Table contains 1m+ records ).
Outer query was not using proper index it always fetching data by using FULL table scan.can someone help me how to optimize it..

**Query**

```
SELECT x 
  FROM UserCardXref x 
 WHERE x.userCardXrefId IN(
    SELECT MAX(y.userCardXrefId) 
      FROM UserCardXref y 
     WHERE y.usrId IN(1001,1002) 
     GROUP 
        BY y.usrId 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
    )
```

**Query Explain**

[image]

**Query Statistics**

[image]

**Execution Plan**

[image]

Comment: you need an index on `userCardXrefId`

Answer (score 0):

I would re-write the query as

```
select x.* from UserCardXref x
join (
 select max(userCardXrefId),usrId from UserCardXref 
 where usrId in (1001,1002) group by usrId
)y on x.userCardXrefId = y.userCardXrefId
```

The indexes you will need as

```
alter table UserCardXref add index userCardXrefId_idx(userCardXrefId)
```

`usrId` is already indexed as per the explain plan so no need to add that

Also you have `having count(*)>0` you are already using max() function and it would never have 0 rows for a given group so I have removed that.

Comment: Thanks @Abhik Chakraborty